# include files on date in directory

Tags: php, arrays, date, include, directory

Allright, I have a overview of sites where I was/am working on. And for every site I have a php file. And in that php file I use this code to get the newest and oldest date of a file what is note a picture in the directory.

```
$date = "test/*.*";
$files = array_filter(glob($date), function($file) {
    $ext = substr($file, strrpos($file, '.'));
    return !in_array($ext, array('.jpg', '.bit', '.png', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.bmp'));
});
$latest = count($files)-1 ;

array_multisort(
    array_map( 'filemtime', $files ),
    SORT_NUMERIC,
    SORT_ASC,
    $files
);
$newestfile = date ("d F Y ", filemtime($files[0]));
$oldestfile = date ("d F Y ", filemtime($files[$latest]));
if($newestfile == $oldestfile) {
    echo  date ("d F Y ", filemtime($files[0]));
} else {
    echo  date ("d F Y ", filemtime($files[0]));
    echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" ;
    echo  date ("d F Y .", filemtime($files[$latest]));
}
```

the output of this code would be like: 16 January 2013    -   25 October 2013 .

In my overview page I use a code to include all the php files (of the websites I've made) to that page. (btw. the php files are not big pages. just with a picture and a bit of text.)

```
$listy = glob("sites/*.php");
print_r ($listy) ;
array_multisort(
    array_map( 'filemtime', $listy ),
    SORT_NUMERIC,
    SORT_DESC,
    $listy
);
if (empty($listy)) {
    include('includes/emptycontent.php');
} else {
    foreach ($listy as $filename) {
        include $filename;
    }
}
```

the output of this array would be like:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => sites/test.php 
    [1] => sites/test2.php 
    [2] => sites/test3.php
```

So far so good, no problems in that.

Now, I want to sort the included files not on time of the included file, like I did in the code above. But i want it to sort on the latest date of the files in the directory like in the php file. so actually I want to combine those to codes to one.
so I have a php file called test. and I want the date of the latest file in the directory also called test. Those have always the same name.

What I thought was to use the output of the second code and then get rid of the "sites/" and the ".php". Those names must be in a array I think. and then for each name get the newestfile and sort them from newest to oldest.

I think like this I get the sites on which I was working recently at the top and the older ones at the bottom of the page.
Maybe my approach is totally wrong but I have no idea how to do that in code.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this bit:

```
array_map( 'filemtime', $listy ),
```

Here, you’re effectively converting a list of files to a list of modification dates. How about converting that into another function. One that finds a most recent file inside a directory:

```
array_map(function ($filename) {
    // $filename = sites/test1.php
    $dir = substr($filename, strlen("sites/"), - strlen(".php")); // cut those! 
    // or:
    $dir = basename($filename, '.php');

    // put the code listing files inside $dir 
    // then sort it (you did it in the first part)
    // and then `return` the most or the least recent one

}, $listy),
```

HTH.

Comment: I think that is a good aproach. But i really don't know how to do that in proper code. I'm sorry, I"m not a really good coder yet. I make a lot of simple mistakes in my code.